# What caused these red blotches on the black suit?

Tags: artifacts

My first question. In several wedding photos the groom's black suit has red blotches on it in the photos. The shots were taken with a Canon 6D with a 70 - 200mm lens at 120mm, ISO 250, 1/400 sec., f/2.8. See photo below for an example. There is a very bright area next to the suit in the set of photos. Thanks for any suggestions.
[image: Red blotches on suit]
All pictures in the set were taken with the same lens.

[image: Uncropped Photo]

Comment: It sure seems like reflections, but they are rather uncommon in form and distribution. I have never seen anything like it before  (I have a 6D and more then 35000 shots with it). Is the lens ultra-dirty maybe? - are all the shots with that issue with the same lens, and do other lenses not have any cases?

Comment: Can you post an uncropped version of the image as well? With lens ghosting, often there is something interesting going on diagonally opposite across the image from the ghosts.

Comment: Seems like lens flare or flare from dirt on a filter. Since the hot is directly into the sun, the strong backlighting exacerbates the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "red blotches" are [lens flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare). If you want to reduce the incidence of lens flare, using a [lens hood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_hood) will help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a reflection from the water and it's making a ghosting effect. Mostly cheap filters do that but sometimes even expensive too.

To fix this problem open the photoshop, select the area with lasso tool, create a layer of hue/saturation (select red color) push the saturation down.

Good luck

Comment: I shall try that in Photoshop to fix them. Thanks.